# Check Now feature for SVN Notifier

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, updates

I’m having trouble testing the Check Now feature in SVN Notifier. I’m assuming that Check Now is supposed to allow the user to check for updates and perhaps pop a update needed system tray balloon if the current folder or file needs to be updated. However, even though my folder needs to be updated (yellow SVN Notifier icon), and right click Check Now. There is no message on whether it needs to be updated or not.

How do I make my Check Now feature functional?

Here's the program I'm using: http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out if I go to tools and then settings. Then change the category to  ‘Default status checking interval when…’ Input 1 hour for ‘…form is active:’ and for ‘form is not active:’ that this will cause a delay for an update. So, if I click on Check Now, a system tray balloon will pop up and tell me it needs updating.